# How does dividing rise/sum result in the slope of a line?

Tags: calculus, slope

I can't get my head around how dividing the differences of two points gives us the inclination of a line. I do understand that the slope will show how much or little a change in $X$ will affect the change in $Y$ but I can't figure out why we find the slope by division. Does division somehow mean average out? If so why?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What metric would you use?  Knowing how much the line climbs vertically given a fixed horizontal step seems like a reasonable one, but others are certainly possible.  You could use the angle of inclination, $\theta$...the ratio is, of course, $\tan \theta$.

Comment: Related: [Why is the slope of a line defined as the change in y over the change in $x$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2074482/139123)

Comment: By the way, it's "rise/run" (or in words, "rise over run"), not "rise/sum".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to MSE!

Let's work with lines through the origin, with the equation $y=mx$. The $+b$ does nothing but shift the line up and down, which does not interact with the slope at all.

As you've noticed, the slope $m$ in the formula $y=mx$ tells you how much the $y$ coordinate changes compared to the $x$ coordinate. For instance, if we change our $x$ coordinate by $1$ (say by moving from $x=3$ to $x=4$) then our $y$ coordinate changes by $m$ (it moves from $y=3m$ to $y=4m$).

In particular, if we know the slope $m$ and the change in $x$ (call it $\Delta x$) then we can compute the change in $y$ (call it $\Delta y$) by $\Delta y = m \Delta x$ (do you see why?).

But we're interested in going the *other direction*. If we know how $y$ changes with respect to $x$, we want to compute the slope. But since division undoes multiplication, we can solve the above equation for $m$ to find

$$m = \frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}$$

as you surely expected.

---

As a quick exercise, what happens if we use the general formula $y=mx+b$ instead of the simplified $y=mx$? Do you see why the $+b$ doesn't change any of our computations? It will have something to do with the fact that we're working with *changes* in $x$ and $y$, whereas the $+b$ doesn't change!

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it really cleared some stuff out in my head. But is there an intuitive way that we end up with division other than it cancels out multiplication? For example, when you want to find the average of something division makes sense since you are basically cutting something in equal parts.

Comment: If you think of the equation as relating the distance you travel to the time you spent then the slope is the average speed, calculated by dividing distance by time.